# How to use Facebook PHP SDK with Heroku?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, heroku

I am totally a novice with Facebook apps, So I used Heroku as a host (because it's free).

But I'm stuck with fetching user's information like username, their friends etc

I dont know how to use the PHP SDK with Heroku, so, if you know please share.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

PS: I like PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i can give you is to look to their documentation : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

And particularly to the permission section : 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/